# how to set currency change(cents) into a superscript using AngularJS currency?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I would like to turn the price tag into this format:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in AngularJS?  Where the decimals are in a superscript format.  So far I'm using this filer `{{ pricetag | currency}}` which displays to:

[image]

If I need to build a custom filter for this, how do I go about?  I'm not familiar with Angular filters, I'm still a noob.

I found this code, but it removes the decimals.  Maybe if I can modify it and grab the decimals in a separate variable.

```
angular.module('your-module', [])
.filter('mycurrency', [ '$filter', '$locale', function ($filter, $locale) {
    var currency = $filter('currency'), formats = $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS;
    return function (amount, symbol) {
        var value = currency(amount, symbol);
        return value.replace(
            new RegExp('\\' + formats.DECIMAL_SEP + '\\d{2}'), '');
    } 
}]);
```

Or do a regex set apart the decimals and turn into two scopes.  Say `scope.price = '24'` and `scope.change = '92'`.  Again, how I would go about splitting the price tag w/ regex.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: The `.replace(new RegExp('\\' + formats.DECIMAL_SEP + '\\d{2}'), '');` at the end removes a decimal separator and 2 digits after it. If you do not need to remove that, remove this `replace`. If you need to add tags around that value, use `.replace(new RegExp('\\' + formats.DECIMAL_SEP + '\\d{2}'), '<sup>$&</sup>');`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using `.replace(new RegExp('\\' + formats.DECIMAL_SEP + '\\d{2}'), '<sup>$&</sup>');`, will print the tags as string '$12<sup>.50</sup>',  not as html.  Is there like a escape notation I need to use inside the replace, so the html elements will display correctly?

Comment: There is something like trustAsHtml() I think. Not sure it will work though.